# Spring Cloud Dataflow local deployer properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using the Spring Cloud Dataflow local server/deployer and upgrading from 1.1.4 to 1.2.3. I've found my stream configs such as value.deserializer are not being passed into the sink process correctly. I have tried both:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.value.deserializer

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.deserializer
```

Neither are working. There seem to be some significant changes with the local deployer. The entire argument list from both common configs and stream configs are visible from the process level now (e.g. using ps). However the stream configs not actually working. Configs work fine when running the Spring Cloud stream app locally.

Any idea what is happening or how I can troubleshoot this? Since Dataflow server is deploying the app it is difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

What you've listed above aren't SCDF or Deployer specific overrides. They are Spring Cloud Stream properties, and from your description, it is unclear how you're passing it to the apps from SCDF.

Once after the applications are deployed (via SCDF), you can access the `/env` or `/configprops` endpoints to verify whether those overrides are applied. If they aren't applied, you can start with the application and its dependencies - compare it with the old stack. Hopefully, that will provide some insights.

If it is still unclear, you can share a sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am passing in the arguments as part of the SCDF stream definition. This is what ended up working. Note I am using multiple Kafka binders.
    --spring.cloud.stream.binders.kafka-qa1.environment.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

Next question, for one stream I need to specify contentType being a Java map class. The UI will not let me enter the / character anymore. Is there a workaround?

app.MyApp.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType=application/x-java-object;type=java.util.Map

Comment: Actually I am able to use java.util.Map without the application/ component.

Comment: Hi, @KevinNiemann. I'm glad you're able to get it working just with `java.util.Map`. Where in the UI it wasn't accepting? Is that at stream deployment time as deployment properties? We would love to fix it if you can share more specifics and/or screenshot.